# Gnome 42 Wayland - nemo-desktop on org-gnome-Nautilus-desktop doesn't work properly

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 22.04, wayland, nemo

Using Wayland with Gnome 42 (default of this distribution), when icons are dragged across nemo-desktop and then released, they are not moved to the new position, always returning to the top left of the desktop. Furthermore, the desktop icons are sometimes transparent and other times they are displayed correctly, arbitrarily depending on whether you deselect or select them.
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop.
Here is a screencast of the Desktop: https://youtu.be/PnYjKAgcQy4
How can I solve the problem?

UPDATE 1:

To solve the problem of icons that do not move on the Desktop, it was sufficient to click with the right mouse button, click on "Customize" and then deactivate the auto-arrange.

The problem of icons becoming transparent, leaving only the titles visible, remains.
How do I fix it?

UPDATE 2:

I posted the same question on Unix&Linux:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/701366
But despite putting a big bounty on the question, I didn't get any answers.
Is there anyone here who can help me?

Comment: You shouldn't cross-post.

Comment: What is cross-post?

Comment: If I don't get an answer, I'm forced to publish it on other StackExchange communities.

Comment: @MarioPalumbo It is not an *absolute* rule but crossposting (or more correctly *multiposting*) is not encouraged. Discussion here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/662263